# Facing Null pointer Exception when fetching data from the server using Volley

Tags: java, android

I want to fetch values from server to an arraylist. For this, I created a Java class called "BackgroundApiTask". On this class, I created a method which return me this arraylist where I add all the values from server. The problem is the returned arrayList is null. Here is the code given below:

```
public ArrayList<CategoryNameWithIconModel> getBookCat(String postData)
    {
        final ArrayList<CategoryNameWithIconModel> bookCatAl = new ArrayList<>();
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        final DialogClass dialogClass = new DialogClass(layoutInflater,context);
        dialogClass.create_spots_dialog();
        dialogClass.show_spots_dialog();

        final String savedata= postData;

        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
                Request.Method.POST,
                URLBookCat,
                null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                        Log.d("Book_Cat", String.valueOf(response));


                        try {

                            for (int i =0; i<response.length();i++)
                            {
                                JSONObject book_cat_object = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                String category_name = book_cat_object.getString("category_name");

                                bookCatAl.add(new CategoryNameWithIconModel(category_name, R.drawable.baseline_star_white_18dp));
                                Log.d("Cat_al_inner", String.valueOf(bookCatAl));

                            }
                            dialogClass.dismiss_spots_dialog();

                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                            Toast.makeText(context,"Server Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            dialogClass.dismiss_spots_dialog();
                        }

                        dialogClass.dismiss_spots_dialog();

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                Toast.makeText(context, "Response error...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                dialogClass.dismiss_spots_dialog();
                // Do something when error occurred
                Log.e("BackgroundApiTask : ",error.toString());
            }
        })
        {
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() {
                try {
                    return savedata == null ? null : savedata.getBytes("utf-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                    Log.d("Unsprted Encoding", URLBookCat);
                    return null;
                }
            }

        };
        //MySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

        Log.d("Cat_al_outer", String.valueOf(bookCatAl));
        return bookCatAl;

    }
```

**Inner ArrayList has values but Outer Arraylist is null.** Please help me to solve this problem..........

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use callback to avoid sync issues. It is better for readability too. 
Besides you should avoid mixing ui and retrieving data.

Next, your are creating a dialog and showing it before result. This is quite strange your are not using `List<CategoryNameWithIconModel>` in `create_spots_dialog` as a parameter or something like.

So as a result your code should looks like this.

You may use differents errors code with a int value instead of boolean one to show custom message for users.

```
public void loadArrayListModel(String postData){

    Callback callback = new Callback(){
        public void onResult(List<String> list, boolean error){
            if(!error){
                // build your array list
                List<CategoryNameWithIconModel> list = new ArrayList<CategoryNameWithIconModel>(list.size());
                for(String s :list){
                    bookCatAl.add(new CategoryNameWithIconModel(category_name, R.drawable.baseline_star_white_18dp));
                }
                // ui loading here with your combo or list view
        final DialogClass dialogClass = new DialogClass(layoutInflater,context);
        // you should add your list here or something like to build your ui 
        dialogClass.create_spots_dialog(list);
        dialogClass.show_spots_dialog();

            }
            // error case
            else{
                Toast.makeText(context,"Server Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
        }
    }
    getBookCat(postData, callback);
}


public void getBookCat(String postData, Callback callback)
    {
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

        final String savedata= postData;

        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
                Request.Method.POST,
                URLBookCat,
                null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                        Log.d("Book_Cat", String.valueOf(response));


                        try {
                            List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
                            for (int i =0; i<response.length();i++)
                            {
                                JSONObject book_cat_object = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                String category_name = book_cat_object.getString("category_name");
                                result.add(category_name);
                                Log.d("Cat_al_inner", String.valueOf(bookCatAl));

                            }
                            callback.onResult(result, false);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                            callback.onResult(null, true);
                        }


                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                callback.onResult(result, false);
                // Do something when error occurred
                Log.e("BackgroundApiTask : ",error.toString());
            }
        })
        {
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() {
                try {
                    return savedata == null ? null : savedata.getBytes("utf-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                    Log.d("Unsprted Encoding", URLBookCat);
                    return null;
                }
            }

        };
        //MySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

        Log.d("Cat_al_outer", String.valueOf(bookCatAl));
        return bookCatAl;

    } 


    public interface Callback {
        void onResult(List<String> list, boolean error);
    }
```

Comment: How you are returning an ArrayList from a void method?